# Windows form app in C# with encrypted app.config, gives error on open if not logged in as an admin

Tags: c#, windows, forms, encryption

I have a windows form application written in C# that has an app.config file with some connection strings that I am encrypting using aspnet_regiis and RSA provider.

I exported the key and imported it on a test machine, added permissions to the key for the user group I am in, and then tried to open the compiled app on this machine. I get an error that windows could not load the RSA provider.

However...  when I give my account administrator rights, the application loads perfectly fine with no error, and is able to read the app.config.

I need this application to run on many users computers that do not have admin rights to their machine. I've followed many tutorials on how to encrypt the app.config file using aspnet_regiis, but none of them ever mentioned needing to be logged in as an administrator in order for the application to be able to use the key when launching the app.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The identity under which you run the application must have rights to the RSA Key Container (if you look at Microsoft's docs on managing Encrypted config and RSA Key Containers you will see how to do that).  The problem is that if you run your app with the user's identity, and that identity can decrypt your RSA Key Container, then you shouldn't bother encrypting it - a determined user could just decrypt it on his own.  You may need to find a better technology for hiding your secrets

Comment: Include the error and some code.